# Creating an object instance with a button click

Tags: c#, instance-variables, buttonclick

I am currently creating a very simple bank account program: The user enters the accountholder name, account number and beginning balance, then presses a "Continue" button to work with that account by making deposits and withdrawals. I wrote a separate `BankAccount` class with the required data members and methods. I've put the code for the creation of the BankAccount object in the `Continue` button click event

```
BankAccount currentAccount = new BankAccount(acctName, acctNum, beginningBalance);
```

But that seems to make it local to that method only, and `currentAccount` is not recognized when I'm programming the click event for the "Record Transactions" (deposits and withdrawals) button.

How and where should the creation of the BankAccount object be coded in order for it to be created when the "Continue" button is clicked and also recognized in the "Record Transactions" button click event? Please let me know if any clarification is needed, or if you need to see part or all of my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the BankAccount object outside the click handler for it to remain in scope. You can instantiate it within the click handler, if that's what you need to do

*The code below has not been tested to compile. It is only to give you an idea of what is required. The exact implementation and method signatures will differ based on whether you're working with Winforms or WPF*

```
BankAccount account = null;

public void Continue_onClickHandler(EventArgs e) {
  account = new BankAccount();
}

public void RecordTransaction_onClickHandler(EventArgs e) {
  if (account == null) {
     throw new Exception("BankAccount has not been instantiated");
  }

  // do whatever you need to do with account here
}
```

Comment: So would it be a data member for the Form itself, then? I would declare it in my Form1 class but outside any method, like I would do with any other class, correct?

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem, fell free to accept this answer (by clicking on the checkmark)